# Using variables in Concordion markdown

Tags: markdown, concordion

When writing a test specification in Concordion, you sometimes want to include the output of a call in the script. For example, I want to test a REST service by posting a new object to it and then verifying that the returned object includes its own URI string. In these circumstances, I think it's right that the format of the URI string is included in the test script rather than buried within a fixture.

Assuming that an object named `newProduct` has been created somehow, I would like to write something like this:

```
When I [post a new product](- "#response=post(#newProduct)")<br/>
Then a [product record](- "#product=getContent(#response)") is returned<br/>
and its [id](- "c:set=#productId=getId(#product)") is [ ](- "c:echo=#productId)")<br/>
and its HAL reference matches [products/#productId](- "?=getHalRef(#product)")
```

Unfortunately the variable `productId` in the last line is not resolved. What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend stating the static format of the URI string in the specification rather than the actual values (which are dynamic and will lead to a different spec each time).

The  fixture can compare the expected and actual formats. This technique is described in the context of date conversion in the [instrumentation documentation](http://concordion.org/instrumenting/java/markdown/#assert-true-and-assert-false-commands).

Using this technique, your Markdown could be written as:

`When I [post a new product](- "#response=post(#newProduct)")<br/>
Then a [product record](- "#product=getContent(#response)") is returned<br/>
with a HAL reference matching [products/#productId](- "?=checkHalRef(#product, #TEXT)") 
( _[#productId](- "#productId=getId(#product)") is [ ](- "c:echo=#productId")_ )`

with the `checkHalRef` method:

`public String checkHalRef(String product, String expected) {
    String halRef = getHalRef(product);
    String expectedHalRef = expected.replace("#productId", getId(product));
    if (halRef.equals(expectedHalRef)) {
        return expected;
    }
    return halRef;
}`

On success, the output documentation would show:

[image: successful example]

and on failure:

[image]

Comment: That's ingenious. I'm working on something else today but will try it as soon as I can. The only difference will be that `product` is not a String but a POJO (an instance of the `Product` class, which will have been converted from XML by an `XStream` instance), so the method of obtaining the actual URI will be different.